# Probability Bookings in a Hotel

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, poisson-process

Hotel has ten rooms, on average 7 are booked per night.

Website enables twelve bookings to be made on a given night.

What is the probability they'll not be able to accommodate all guests on given night.

State any assumptions you make.

**My initial thoughts were poisson. P(11) + P(12) guests show up on a night which is 7.2% and assumption being all bookings are independent.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Any specific reason why you think your answer is wrong?

Comment: It was a question on a recent maths paper which I failed to pass and I specifically remember this question was one I asked someone after the class and they mentioned not using the poisson so I simply assumed I used the wrong method although I can't seem to find an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can use Poisson distribution:
$$\mathbf P(X=k)=\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}$$ where $X$ is the random variable that deals with the no. of guests in the hotel. Note that $\lambda=7$.

The answer is therefore: $$\mathbf P(X\geq 11)=1-\sum_{k=0}^{10} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} e^{-\lambda}$$ because we know that the hotel cannot accommodate more than $10$ guests.

Comment: Does it not have a cap though because the total amount that can be booked is 12 therefore it would be 1 - p(11) + p(12)

Comment: But, can the hotel accommodate 13 guests? Or 14? Even that needs to be included, right?

Comment: No as I said the hotel has 10 rooms. I assume bookings are independent and rooms are single ie 1 guest = 1 room. Thanks very much btw